# Using grep or sed to substitute words not matching a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am new to the regular expression paradigm and I've encountered a problem I'm trying to solve, with no success.

Imagine a file test.txt with:

```
hello everyone, whatsi up
i hope my program worksa
if it doesnt... ho well!
```

I would like to output to another file output.txt only the words that start with a consonant and end with a vowel so it would result in:

```
hello whatsi
hope worksa
ho
```

I am using `grep -o '\b[^ aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\b' test.txt > output.txt` however, the `-o` flag outputs every matched string onto a new line. What should I do to get the format that I want? Another valid option would be to substitute everything that doesn't match that pattern with a blank space using sed but I failed to do it as well. Should I be using sed or awk instead?

Thanks

Comment: What if `doesnt...` was `do...` instead? Would you expect to see `do` in the output or not? You need to include cases where your "words" are surrounded by more than just white space in your sample if that can happen in the real world or you'll get solutions that work for your posted sample input but not for your real input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following awk solution could help you in same too.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(tolower($i) ~ /^[^aeiou].*[aeiou]$/){val=val?val OFS $i:$i}};print val;val=""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
hello whatsi
hope worksa
ho
```

Adding a non-one liner form with explanation too here.

```
awk '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){       ##Starting a for loop here which starts from variable i value from 1 to till the value of NF(number of fields) value.
  if(tolower($i) ~ /^[^aeiou].*[aeiou]$/){ ##checking here condition if a field value in lower is satisfying the regex where I am checking if a value NOT starts from vowel and it is ending with vowels.
    val=val?val OFS $i:$i ##Creating a variable named val which will have value of current field value and it will concatenate its own value.
}
};
  print val;              ##Outside of loop, I am printing the value of variable val here, which will have all those words which are satisfying your conditions.
  val=""                  ##Nullifying the value of variable val here.
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That will fail when the target words are not surrounded by white space. Try changing `doesnt...` to `do...` or `well!` to `we` in the sample input. It's only poorly chosen sample input/output that makes it appear to work.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and word boundaries:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\\<[^aeiou][[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\\>' 'RT{print RT}' file
hello
whatsi
hope
worksa
ho
```

If you need to preserve the original lines breaks then using GNU awk for FPAT instead of RS would be:

```
$ gawk -v FPAT='\\<[^aeiou][[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\\>' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
hello whatsi
hope worksa
ho
```

Comment: This does not preserve the newlines as in the original file.

Comment: my answer with `grep` is got down-vote and yours with the same output is getting up-vote :) I think because you are famous and I am NOT.

Comment: @k-five and Ed-morton: You guys gave me a good laugh. BTW nice solution K-five and Ed. +1 to both of you.

Comment: @glennjackman I've updated my answer now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Glad to help. After all, you are **THE** Ed Morton! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can instruct `grep` to treat the input as a set of null-byte-terminated lines, i.e. as one long line if your input does not contain null bytes, with the `-z`/`--null-data` flag.

That way you can preserve newline characters (note `...| |\n` in the end):

```
$ grep -Pozi '\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]\w*[aeiou]\b| |\n' file
hello  whatsi 
 hope   worksa
   ho
```

but at the expense of null-byte (`\x0`) characters present (and multiple spaces, due to our regex). Those can be fixed with a few `sed` expressions:

```
$ grep -Pozi '\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]\w*[aeiou]\b| |\n' file \
  | sed -E -e 's/\x0//g' -e 's/ +/ /g' -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ $//'
hello whatsi
hope worksa
ho
```

(one to strip null-bytes, one to replace multiple spaces with a single space, and two to strip leading and trailing spaces).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-n` option to output line number, you can then regroup the matches.

For example, in Perl:

```
grep -no '\b[^ aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\b' test.txt \
| perl -aF: -nwE 'chomp $F[1];
                push @{ $b[ $F[0] ] }, $F[1]
                }{ say "@$_" for grep defined, @b'
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl by itself will work well here: for each line, find each word matching the criteria

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", grep {/\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz][[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\b/i} @F' file
```

- using `-a` splits the line into words, stored in the array `@F`
- `grep` will filter only the words matching the regular expression
- then join the resulting list with spaces and print them out.

  - if no words on a line match, then an empty line will be printed.

Golfing a touch

```
perl -lape'$_="@{[grep{/\b(?=[a-z])[^aeiou][a-z]*[aeiou]\b/i}@F]}"' file
```

Note that a digit matches `[^aeiou]` which is why I added the lookahead `(?=[a-z])` to restrict the first character of the word to be alphabetic but not a vowel.

Answer (score 2):

with the help of `-P` in `grep`

---

```
~ ❱ grep -Po '\w+' file
hello
everyone
whatsi
up
i
hope
my
program
worksa
if
it
doesnt
ho
well
~ ❱ grep -Po '\b(?![oauie])[a-z]+((?=[oauie]).)\b' file
hello
whatsi
hope
worksa
ho
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # return in a single line:
s~ ❱ grep -zPo '\b(?![oauie])[a-z]+((?=[aeiou]).) \b' file
hello whatsi hope ho ~❱
~ ❱ 
~ ❱
```

---

**how it works**

`-P` is for using `PCRE`

and the pattern follows these steps:

1. it does not match any `[aieuo]` at the beginning of a word
2. then matches some characters `[a-z]+` if:
3. the end of that word has `[aieuo]`

---

**NOTE**

My answer does NOT keep the words in its line. I wanted to write a **Perl one-liner** and then noticed `@glenn jackman` already did this. Thus you can use that answer or:

```
~ ❱ perl -lae' print for "@{[ grep{/\b(?![oauie])[a-z]+((?=[oauie]).)\b/} @F ]}" ' file                                                                                                       
hello whatsi                                                                                                                                                                                           
hope worksa
ho
~ ❱
```

or without `"@{[ ... ]}` operators:

```
~ ❱ perl -lae '@arr = grep /\b(?![oauie])[a-z]+((?=[oauie]).)\b/, @F;print "@arr"' file
hello whatsi
hope worksa
ho
~ ❱
```

Comment: This misses the point of the question: the OP already knows about `grep -o`, but he wants to keep the lines "intact"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex to match words that start with a consonant and end with a vowel

```
/\<[^ aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\>/
```

which we can use to select our words and remove everything else using Ex/Vim editor.

So given the `test.txt` file created by the following command:

```
$ printf "hello everyone, whatsi up\ni hope my program worksa\nif it doesnt... ho well!" > test.txt
```

this shell command will read the file and save parsed output into `out.txt` file:

```
$ ex -s +'%s/\<\w\+\>\(\<[^ aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\>\)\@<!\s\?//g' +"%s/\([[:punct:]]\+\)//g" +%p +'wq! out.txt' test.txt 
hello  whatsi 
hope worksa
 ho
```

Explanation:

- `\<\w\+\>` - selects all words;
- `\(\<[^ aeiouAEIOU]\w*[aeiouAEIOU]\>\)` - selects our words to keep;
- `\@<!` - it matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match just before what follows (see: `:help \@<!`);
- `%s/pattern/replace/g` - substitutes the pattern with replace text;
- `%s/\([[:punct:]]\+\)//g` - removes all punctuation characters;
- `+%p` - prints the file buffer to the standard output;
- `wq! file.txt` - writes the current buffer to the file;

Above solution is based on this answer: [How to remove all words which doesn't match the pattern?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13810/467)